# Parsing a custom DATE_FORMAT with DateTime in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

How do I get DateTime to parse a custom date format(i.e. 'x-%Y')?

I've set the format within an initializer with (as per the [RoR API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html)):

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:x_year] = 'x-%Y'
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:x_year] = 'x-%Y'
```

and when I call:

```
DateTime.strptime('x-2011', 'x-%Y')
```

The correct result is returned, but

```
DateTime.parse('x-2011')
```

Throws an

```
ArgumentError: invalid date
```

Comment: Its probably worth mentioning that the 'x-%Y' format is an arbitrary format for the purposes of this question. I'm actually dealing with '%m/%d/%Y %M:%I %p'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

never heard of such a possibility. However, you could still do something like:

```
class DateTime
  class << self
    alias orig_parse parse
  end
  def self.parse(string, format = nil)
    return DateTime.orig_parse(string) unless format
    DateTime.strptime(string, Date::DATE_FORMATS[format])
  end
end

in your example it might look like that:

Date::DATE_FORMATS.merge!({:xform => "x-%Y"})
DateTime.parse('x-2011', :xform) #=> Sat, 01 Jan 2011 00:00:00 +0000
```

You could get rid of 'format' attribute and iterate && validate/rescue through DATE_FORMATS instead

Comment: The answer seems like it will work but I suspect that the underlying implementation should be doing something similar. I have a feeling like its a configuration that should be able to be set and re-used throughout the application.